# Как анимировать смену одного контрола на другой?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

В зависимости от привязанной к `ContentPresenter` `Vm-ки`, на экране отображаются разные `UserControl`. Можно ли как-то отловить момент смены одного контрола на другой, чтобы санимировать этот переход?

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding VmBase}">
        <ContentPresenter.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vmR:LoginVm}">
                <uc:LoginPage></uc:LoginPage>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vmR:SignUpVm}">
                <uc:SignUpPage></uc:SignUpPage>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentPresenter.Resources>
</ContentPresenter>
```

Comment: Не решение, но [ContentControl с переходами](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/develop/MahApps.Metro/Controls/TransitioningContentControl.cs) есть в [метрошном паке контролов](http://mahapps.com/controls/transitioning-content-control.html). Посмотрите, может, что полезное почерпнёте.

Comment: А почему не решение?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Окей, комментарий <del>@Squidward</del> @Athari на самом деле правильный: в Mahapps.Metro есть нужный контрол с несколькими предопределёнными анимациями. Но давайте напишем такой контрол самостоятельно.

Перед нами стоят две проблемы. Во-первых, мы должны запомнить старый контент перед тем, как он исчезнет, чтобы правильно показать его на время анимации. Во-вторых, для показа одновременно и старого, и нового контента нам нужны *два* `ContentPresenter`'а.

Для этого воспользуемся промежуточным контролом, который будет содержать эти самые два `ContentPresenter`'а.

Итак, создаём новый контрол, назовём его `AnimatableContentPresenter`. Мы создаёт custom control, а не `UserControl`. (Это делается через *Проект* → *Add* → *New Item...* → *WPF* → *Custom Control (WPF)* в Visual Studio.)

Для начала, код с комментариями.

```
// объявляем, что в шаблоне должна быть предоставлена анимация, которую мы запустим
[TemplatePart(Name = "PART_Animation", Type = typeof(Storyboard))]
public class AnimatableContentPresenter : Control
{
    static AnimatableContentPresenter()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(AnimatableContentPresenter),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(AnimatableContentPresenter)));
    }

    Storyboard animation; // текущая анимация
    bool isAnimationRunning = false;

    #region dp object Content, on change OnContentChanged
    public object Content
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(ContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ContentProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Content", typeof(object), typeof(AnimatableContentPresenter),
            new PropertyMetadata(OnContentChangedStatic));

    static void OnContentChangedStatic(
        DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var self = (AnimatableContentPresenter)d;
        self.OnContentChanged(e.OldValue, e.NewValue);
    }
    #endregion

    #region dp object PreviousContent
    public object PreviousContent
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(PreviousContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PreviousContentProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PreviousContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "PreviousContent", typeof(object), typeof(AnimatableContentPresenter));
    #endregion

    // когда Content поменяется...
    void OnContentChanged(object oldContent, object newContent)
    {
        if (isAnimationRunning)
            animation?.Stop();

        // ... запомним старый Content в PreviousContent
        PreviousContent = oldContent;

        // и перезапустим анимацию
        if (animation != null)
        {
            animation.Begin();
            isAnimationRunning = true;
        }
    }

    // при появлении шаблона, вычитаем из него анимацию
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        if (animation != null)
            animation.Completed -= OnAnimationCompleted;

        if (isAnimationRunning)
        {
            // TODO: начать новую анимацию там, где предыдущая завершилась?
            animation?.Stop();
        }

        animation = (Storyboard)Template.FindName("PART_Animation", this);

        if (animation != null) // подпишемся на завершение анимации
            animation.Completed += OnAnimationCompleted;
    }

    // по окончанию анимации...
    private void OnAnimationCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // выбросим старый контент
        PreviousContent = null;
        // сбросим эффект анимации
        animation.Remove();
        isAnimationRunning = false;
    }
}
```

Теперь нам нужен шаблон в `Themes\Generic.xaml` (его вам уже, скорее всего, положил мастер создания нового контрола).

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:AnimatableContentPresenter}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:AnimatableContentPresenter}">
                <!-- несколько трюков с layout manager'ом, чтобы
                     избежать умножения через конвертер -->
                <Grid Name="Root" ClipToBounds="True">
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <!-- ширина вдвое больше Root -->
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition
                                Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Root}"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition
                                Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Root}"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <!-- растянем на всю ширину -->
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                            <!-- старый контент -->
                            <ContentPresenter
                                Content="{TemplateBinding PreviousContent}"
                                Style="{x:Null}"
                                Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Root}"/>
                            <!-- текущий контент -->
                            <ContentPresenter
                                Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                Style="{x:Null}"
                                Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Root}"/>
                            <!-- анимируемая распорка -->
                            <Grid Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Root}"
                                  Name="Strut">
                                <Grid.Resources>
                                    <Storyboard x:Key="Animation" x:Name="PART_Animation">
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="Strut"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                            From="0"
                                            Duration="0:0:0.4">
                                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"
                                                                 Exponent="1.2"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                        </DoubleAnimation>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </Grid.Resources>
                            </Grid>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Отлично, большая часть работы готова. Теперь нам нужно представить это как стиль для чего-нибудь — например, для `ContentControl`'а. (Это штука наподобие `ContentPresenter`'аб немного более высокоуровневая.)

Кладём в нашем окне (или ресурсах приложения) стиль:

```
<Style TargetType="ContentControl" x:Key="LeftToRightAnimatedContentControl">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:AnimatableContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Испытываем.

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding}"
                Style="{StaticResource LeftToRightAnimatedContentControl}"/>
```

Получаем вот такую анимацию:

[image: анимашка]

Comment: Спасибо, крутой ответ!

Comment: Разобрался как все работает, только вот одна строчка немного непонятна `[TemplatePart(Name = "PART_Animation", Type = typeof(Storyboard))]`.

Comment: @Lightness: Это строчка декларирует, что в шаблоне (том, который в Generic.xaml) должен быть элемент с именем `PART_Animation` типа `Storyboard`. Мы этот элемент используем в коде потом. Это как бы документация для тех, кто пишет стиль, что коду требуется наличие в шаблоне элемента с таким именем и такого типа.

Comment: @Lightness: Пожалуйста!

Comment: Появилась надобность использовать разные анимации при смене контролов. Получается для каждой анимации нужно создавать `<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:AnimatableContentPresenter}">` с созданием нового `Template`?

Comment: @Lightness: Ну, в принципе да, достаточно поменять визуальную часть, то есть стиль/template.

Answer (score 1):

Это надо делать DataTrigger + StoryBoard (вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80388/wpf-data-triggers-and-story-boards) пример есть). Цепляешься в твоем случае к свойствам IsLoginFineshed  (к примеру) и на него цепляешь анимацию.