# Производительность при анимации

Tags: wpf

Господа, помогите разобраться с анимацией в WPF приложение. Даже самая простая анимация с изменением цвета, размера или еще какого то свойства - сильно нагружает процессор (у меня лично на 20% загрузка висит). Помогите разобраться с этим. Уж больно хочется сделать "живое" приложение, но с таким успехом я лучше картинок понапихаю)...

Comment: (1) Смена картинок — намного более тяжёлая операция, чем анимация. Так что вы так ничего не выиграете. (2) А покажите вашу анимацию на воспроизводящем примере. И да, что у вас за система?

Comment: [По данным примерам делаю](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/16.2.php) Картинки я имею ввиду - GIF. Система win 10

Comment: Открой проводник и начни изменять размер окна. Процессор так же улетит под 20 - 25 %. Перерисовка у винды занимает много ресурсов. На 2х ядерном ЦПУ будет под 50%.

Comment: Ну с этим как то бороться можно? Мне нужна простейшая анимация поворачивать объект пока он виден, но если он так будет грузить, то тогда это большая проблема..)

Comment: @Chloroform: У меня долгое изменение размеров окна Visual Studio с частотой где-то в 5 герц даёт загрузку процессора на процентов 5 визуально. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ: В тех примерах ничего такого криминального не видно. А попробуйте на вашей машине вот такую анимашку: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/543348/10105. На моей старой машине она летала (быстрее, чем 25 кадров в секунду, нужные для gif'а), а на новой так и подавно.

Comment: @VladD: Хм, что то я данный пример даже запустить не смог. Создал пустой WPF проект, сделал все так, как там и в итоге пустое окно. Я так понимаю там надо еще что то сделать? [Сам код](https://1drv.ms/f/s!As59A-ax0pyjmJ1diiXuFpUOGOOaGA)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ: Ну, у вас есть Binding, а где устанавливается `DataContext`? И где определяется `DataTemplate` типа данных, который показывается?

Comment: @VladD: Весь день пытался привязать к нему нужные элементы и в итоге выводит только 1, не до конца я понимаю как тот способ работает. Можно простой пример данных?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ: Ну, вы привязываете один элемент, а через 1 секунду другой, например.

Comment: @VladD: Ага, разобрался. Раз в секунду по таймером загонял в него другой элемент. Заработал. И по нагрузке хочу сказать, что весьма не плохо, всего 0.5% максимум. Теперь вот разобраться как реализовать у себя подобным образом анимацию скажем выдвигания объекта, или медленный поворот на 360 градусов элемент...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ: Тогда разбирайтесь, что именно анимируется в том коде, сравнивайте. Задавайте вопросы :)