# Переход перелистыванием страниц

Tags: c#, wpf

Такая задача - имеется главное окно содержащее Frame. Необходимо сделать плавный переход между страницами (Как, например, лендинг). То есть первая страница уходит вверх и одновременно с этим следующая появляется снизу. А главная проблема, что я перехожу между страницами с помощью кнопок на них. Возможно здесь не надо использовать фрейм? Не уверен. Заранее спасибо за любые ответы.

Comment: Менять контент просто — подменяйте VM и используйте `ContentPresenter`. Чтобы анимировать смену контента, посмотрите сюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/543348/10105

Comment: @VladD Очень громоздкое решение через эти презентеры

Comment: Без MVVM было бы короче. Но при этом у вас не будет MVVM. Choose your poison.

Comment: @VladD На самом деле я просто не особо разобрался в коде. На WPF недавно совсем перешел. Я думал возможно как-то попроще реализовать, мол делаем такую анимацию - у одной страницы уменьшаем высоту, а у другой увеличиваем (Это первое, что в голову пришло)

Comment: Ну, эта анимация просто двигает старую страницу вверх, а новую сдвигает на её место. Там всё просто, если разобраться.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как анимировать смену одного контрола на другой?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542254/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%83-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9)