# Изменение размеров Frame влияет на пропорции Page

Tags: wpf, .net

Делаю слайдовую анимацию для смены содержимого во Frame, страницы должны плавно менять одна другую. Для этого хочу анимировать высоту Frame, но при изменении свойства Height меняется и содержимое в Page (сжимается Grid). Подскажите как можно этого избежать или дайте совет, если есть другой простой способ.

Comment: Советую вам отказаться от `Frame` и использовать что то вроде [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/543348/220553).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо, интересное решение, только у меня не работает. ContentControl ничего не отображает

Comment: Значит что то делаете не то и это уже надо задать отдельным вопросом с указанием всего необходимого. Но от `Frame` советую все же отказаться, ибо с ним далеко вы не уедете!