# Допустимо ли подписываться на события ViewModel из View

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Где-то слышал, что не рекомендуется подписываться на события VM из View.
У меня в VM есть событие `public event Action SomeEvent` на которое я подписываюсь в конструкторе страницы

```
public MyPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var ViewModel = new ViewModel();
    DataContext = ViewModel;
    ViewModel.SomeEvent += SomeMethod;
}
```

При срабатывании события метод `SomeMethod` на стороне View производит некоторые изменения.
Допустима ли такая конструкция и какие могут быть альтернативы?

Comment: Моя точка зрения: если вы выносите некоторый интерфейс `IVM`, который будет содержать это событие, а `VM` будет реализовывать этот интерфейс, то такая зависимость от интерфейса вполне допустима. Зависеть от реализации, конечно, нехорошо. Но, возможно, тут стоит объявить об этой зависимости явно, например, запрашивая ее в конструкторе. Также стоит продумать вопрос о том, что делать при `DataContextChanged`, ведь тот кто владеет вашей вьюхой, имеет право изменить у нее DataContext

Comment: @АндрейNOP, спасибо. А что вы имеете в виду под объявить явно в конструкторе?

Comment: Имею ввиду конструктор с параметром, вы вот привели код, а что в нем такое VM? Откуда оно берется?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, это ViewModel. Изменил код для наглядности

Comment: Ну вот так точно нехорошо писать, View не должна создавать сама себе VM, это не ее обязанность

Comment: @АндрейNOP, а как лучше? Можно об этом где-то подробно почитать?

Comment: DataContext должен устанавливать тот, кто создает вашу вьюху

Comment: @Mihail: Вопрос в том, _для чего_ вам нужна такая подписка. Не хотите ли вы случайно вынести бизнес-логику во View? Если да, то вы делаете неправильно.

Comment: @VladD, по этому событию происходит смена содержимого + анимация

Comment: @VladD, вообще я не очень понимаю как правильно работать с анимацией с MVVM. Вопрос в том, где она должна быть описана и как ее запускать. Если не трудно, то напишите пару строк:
[вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/913710/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-viewmodel)

Comment: Смена содержимого должна быть в VM, а View должна узнавать о ней через привязку. Делать специальное событие для запуска анимации вообще неправильно: запуск анимации должен быть доброй волей View. Если вам нужно анимировать смену контента, это можно делать, например, так: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/543348/10105

Answer (score 1):

Если делаеш через MVVM то используй команды вместо событий, во `ViewModel`:

```
    private RelayCommand someCommand;
    public RelayCommand SomeCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return someCommand ??
              (someCommand = new SomeCommand(obj =>
              {
                  SomeMethod();
              }));
        }
    }
```

Реализация RelayCommand:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> execute;
    private Func<object, bool> canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        this.execute = execute;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return this.canExecute == null || this.canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this.execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

А в контроле который должен выполнять команду просто пропиши:

```
Command="{Binding SomeCommand}"
```

Comment: Каким боком тут команды? Команда это то что дёргают снаружи, чтобы попросить выполнить некую операцию, а у ТС наоборот, VM что-то делает самостоятельно и потом оповещает View