# Как сделать автоматическое перелистывание картинок с плавной анимацией wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, frame

Кто знает, как сделать автоматическое перелистывание картинок во frame окна в wpf с плавной анимацией, подскажите, пожалуйста, я даже не знаю как это реализовать.
Пробовал создавать массив изображений, и в цикле перелистывать их. Не получилось.

Comment: Что значит "автоматическое перелистывание"? Карусель?

Comment: Нет, не карусель. Надо, чтобы картинки менялись поочередно, как бы перелистываясь. Как, например на сайте nvidia на главное странице, только с анимацией листания с права на лево.

Comment: Это и называется "карусель") Термин наверно с Web пошел, не знаю, вот к примеру [первая ссылка гугла с описанием](https://itchief.ru/bootstrap/carousel). Ну а так, это дубликат [данного вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/543348/220553), так что смотрите, изучайте, пробуйте.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, не знал что это каруселью называется, только начал изучать все это.