# Индекс в Binding WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Можно ли использовать индексаторы в Binding? Если да, то каким образом?

По логике в TextBlock в DataContext я указываю индекс объекта из списка, И ему присваиваются свойства из этого объекта, но это не работает.

Необходимо для переключения стилей этих TextBlock и анимации пролистывания страницы при нажатии на кнопку.

View

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="#FFCEF4F7">
            <StackPanel
                Orientation="Horizontal"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center">

                <TextBlock  
                    DataContext="{Binding Path=Steps[0]}"
                    Style="{DynamicResource stepRegistrationStyle}"
                    Text="{Binding Path=Name}"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsShow}"/>

                <TextBlock  
                    DataContext="{Binding Steps[1]}"
                    Style="{DynamicResource stepRegistrationStyle}"
                    Text="{Binding Path=Name}"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsShow}"/>
                
                <TextBlock  
                    DataContext="{Binding Path=Steps[2]}"
                    Style="{DynamicResource stepRegistrationStyle}"
                    Text="{Binding Path=Name}"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsShow}"/>

                <TextBlock  
                    DataContext="{Binding Path=Steps[3]}"
                    Style="{DynamicResource stepRegistrationStyle}"
                    Text="{Binding Path=Name}"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsShow}"/>

                <TextBlock  
                    DataContext="{Binding Path=Steps[4]}"
                    Style="{DynamicResource stepRegistrationStyle}"
                    Text="{Binding Path=Name}"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsShow}"/>

                <Button Margin="5" Width="50" Click="Previos" Content="Previos"/>
                <Button Margin="5" Width="50" Click="Next" Content="Next"/>
            </StackPanel>

        </Grid>
```

Model:

```
internal class StepRegistrationModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _name;
        private bool _isShow;
        private string _prop;

        public string Name
        {
            get => _name;
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                OnChangeProperty("Name");
            }
        }
        public string Prop
        {
            get => _prop;
            set
            {
                _prop = value;
                OnChangeProperty("Prop");
            }
        }
        public bool IsShow
        {
            get => _isShow;
            set
            {
                _isShow = value;
                OnChangeProperty("IsShow");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
        public void OnChangeProperty([CallerMemberName] string prop = "") =>
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
```

ViewModel

```
internal class ApplicationViewModels : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<StepRegistrationModel> Steps = new ObservableCollection<StepRegistrationModel>()
        {
            new StepRegistrationModel()
            {
                Name = "1. General Information",
                Prop = "generalInformation",
                IsShow = true,
            },
            new StepRegistrationModel()
            {
                Name = "2. Select Exchange",
                Prop = "selectExchange",
                IsShow = false
            },
            new StepRegistrationModel()
            {
                Name = "1. General Information",
                Prop = "generalInformation",
                IsShow = true,
            },
            new StepRegistrationModel()
            {
                Name = "2. Select Exchange",
                Prop = "selectExchange",
                IsShow = false
            }
        };

        private int _actualPage = 0;
        public ApplicationViewModels()
        {
            
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
        public void OnChangeProperty([CallerMemberName] string prop = "") =>
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));

        internal void NextPage()
        {
            if(_actualPage == Steps.Count-1)
                return;
            _actualPage++;

            Steps.ToList().ForEach(x => x.IsShow = false);
            Steps[_actualPage].IsShow = true;
            OnChangeProperty("Steps");
        }

        internal void PreviosPage()
        {
            if (_actualPage == 0)
                return;
            _actualPage--;

            Steps.ToList().ForEach(x => x.IsShow = false);
            Steps[_actualPage].IsShow = true;
            OnChangeProperty("Steps");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Нет, индексов нету. XAML не про индексы, он вообще не должен знать что-либо про данные, а вы это от него хотите. Вы можете сделать конвертор, но это костыль, да и, по сути, нарушение MVVM.  Да и вообще ваша задача в целом, это нарушение MVVM, ибо вы пытаетесь заставить View слой управлять ViewModel (как кстати и `Click`, ибо в MVVM клик это `ICommand`). Ваша задача решается [примерно так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/543348/220553), где при изменении свойства, XAML лишь воспроизводит нужную анимацию, а VM слой меняет [контент](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/765122/220553).

Comment: Если вопрос про навигацию, то вот еще решение https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266479/373567